# How can i change the screen brightness of my laptop in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have an acer aspire 5749 notebook with the latest version of Ubuntu(12.04 i guess), so when i change the brightness with the hot-key the brightness pane changes but actually the brightness remains the same. pleaze help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

And then type your root password and insert these lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Save and exit.

`sudo update-grub`

Restart your laptop and then it should work by the "Fn" + left and right arrows.

Comment: This knocks out my ability to slide the brightness in system preferences and removes the hotkeys in 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

i also have the acer aspire series laptop, and the hotkeys do not work, so you can change it by following command `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 f4.b=00`, here you can enter value from 00 to ff in hexadecimal, [00 = bright and ff = dull]

for more details go through the following link : http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-increasedecrease-brightness-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so before anyone messes with

```
sudo update-grub
```

The latest ubuntu versions use grub2

So, pretty please use:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

If you don't, your system won't boot and you have to get your hands messy.

Comment: There is no difference between update-grub and update-grub2.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/167763/what-is-difference-between-update-grub-and-update-grub2

Answer (score 0):

install xbacklight

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then to decrease brightness

```
xbacklight -dec {any value between 0-100}
```

to increase brightness

```
xbacklight -inc {any value between 0-100}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and using nouveau. I solved this problem by:

1. In terminal type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. There search for the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `acpi_osi=Linux  acpi_backlight=native` inside the " ".
   (If this does not work try "vendor" or "video" in place of native (of course without the quotes)).
3. Now run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

This does not make your brightness function keys work but is a workaround.

Install Brightness Controller with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
```

For Version 1 with up to 4 Monitor Support:

```
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller-simple
```

For Version 2 with Multi-Monitor Support and other features:

```
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 19.10 right now on my Dell Inspiron. I was unable to change the brightness using function keys or even the slider in the top menu bar. For previous versions of Ubuntu, brightness never worked for me. So this is the solution that finally worked for me.

You need to edit the GRUB2:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Try to find this following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change this following line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Update the GRUB configuration after the above changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

and you are good to go. If the above changes doesn't work for you, try any one of the following changes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=native"
```

Answer (score 0):

At first we need some information about the video card. Just to make sure the right one is working. For example it is a APU (CPU+GPU in one processor). Intel or AMD does not matter. In my example it is an i5 470U processor. For further use we need the ID of the graphic card:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep VGA

--> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor 
    Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
The ID is 0:2:0
```

For further information about the vide device use

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
```

We need to edit/create a config file for xorg:

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

For our example the following section has to be inserted:

```
Section "Device"
      Identifier "Intel Graphics"
      Driver "intel"
      Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
      BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
      EndSection
Section "Device"
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/Intel/

Then the grub bootloader has to be edited to rewrite the list of supported OS.
This Bios option was introduced during the time of windows vista.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bootoptionen/

Grub editieren and extend the following line with acpi_osi=Linux in

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Close file and update grub

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the System.

```
$ reboot
```

The keys (with the sun symbol) on your keyboard for regulating the brightness should work now.

(copy paste from
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115249/brightness-key-not-working-acer-aspire-v15/1306830#1306830 )

Comment: tested with Ubuntu 20.04 lts und 16.04 lts.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with my brand new laptop, and the solution ended up being to simply **update to the latest ubuntu version** (from 20.04.4 -> 22.04 in my case) and the problem was solved.